# Query on Groups in Tableau

Tags: grouping, tableau-api

I have created one group with products.
In the product group I have added some mobiles according to brand wise (apple, redmi, Samsung, LG, etc) and saved the file.

My question is, if one new mobile model came (suppose apple model 12), will the apple iPhone model 12 added to the already created product group or should we add to the group manually???

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try? Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created group by brand then any new products should automatically get mapped in Tableau provided the mapping is present in the data set.

If you have created group using different products then you will have to manually add any new products. To avoid this, use the above mentioned process.